# What is equivalent of the math.h library in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone

I am using the exp and pow functions in a program for iPhone, which would use the math.h library if I was programming in C. What is the equivalent I need to use in iPhone SDK so my two functions will work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can continue you use math.h :)

Just

```
#include <math.h>
```

Comment: wouldn't it be #include"math.h" or no?

Comment: No, it's `#include <math.h>` since it's a standard system header, part of iPhone's BSD heritage.

Comment: sweet ok. then i guess my code is wrong then cuz it's not giving right answer :) Ty so much! Glad importing the math library for my two functions won't be an ordeal :)

Answer (score 0):

math.h as described here

http://www.iphonedevforums.com/forum/general-development-questions-advice/196-math-functions-how-find.html